# node.js + cheerio scrape: Passing an array of urls to download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, scrape, cheerio

Firstly, here is my code as I've progressed so far:

```
var http = require("http");

// Utility function that downloads a URL and invokes
// callback with the data.
function download(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).on("error", function() {
    callback(null);
  });
}

var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var url = "http://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/all";
var myArray = [];
var a = 0;

var getLinks = function(){download(url, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    // console.log(data);
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    $(".content").each(function(i, e) {
      var blogName = $(e).find(".blog-name").text();
      var followLink = $(e).find("a").attr("href");
      var blogSite = $(e).find(".description").text();

      myArray[a] = [a];
      myArray[a]["blogName"] = blogName;
      myArray[a]["followLink"] = "http://www.bloglovin.com"+followLink;
      myArray[a]["blogSite"] = blogSite;

      a++;

      console.log(myArray);

    });
  }
});
}

getLinks();
```

As you can see, `followLinks` is concatenated to `followUrl`, of which I'd like to pass through the `'url'` download, so effectively I'll be scraping each of the pages using the same CSS rules, which will be added to the multidimensional array for the corresponding blogger.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Two calls to include `http` module ? Please remove one of them

Comment: that was a pasting error!

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in one of my scraping jobs, but I use the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to accomplish. Note that I'm also using the [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) module and [cheerio.js](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) in my scraping. I fetch and scrape rows of data from a single webpage, but suspect you could do something similar to fetch URLs and request / scrape them in the same manner.

I also admit this is quite basic coding, certainly could be optimized with a bit of refactoring. Hope it gives you some ideas at least...

First, I use request to fetch the page and call my parse function -

```
var url = 'http://www.target-website.com';
function(lastCallback) {
    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
        if(!err) { parsePage(err, resp, body, lastCallback); }
          else { console.log('web request error:' + resp.statusCode); }
    }
}
```

Next, in my `parsePage` function, I load the website into Cheerio, fetch the HTML of each data row into an array, push my `parseRow` function and each HTML segment into another array, and use `async.parallel` to process each iteration -

```
var rows = [];
function parsePage(err, resp, body, callback1) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('div#targetTable tr').each(function(i, elem) {
        rows.push($(this).html());
    });

    var scrRows = [];
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        scrRows.push(function(callback2) {
            parseRow(err, resp, row);
            callback2();
    });

    async.parallel(scrRows, function() {
        callback1();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `a = 0;` So

```
myArray[a] = [a]; // => myArray[0] = [0]; myArray[0] becomes an array with 0 as only member in it
```

All these statements throw an error since Array can have only integer as keys.

```
myArray[a]["blogName"] = blogName;
myArray[a]["followLink"] = "http://www.bloglovin.com"+followLink;
myArray[a]["blogSite"] = blogSite;
```

Instead try this:

```
var obj = { 
  index: a,
  blogName: blogName,
  followLink: "http://www.bloglovin.com" + followLink,
  blogSite: blogSite
}

myArray.push(obj);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, just create an object with the properties you scrape then push that object onto your array.

```
var blogInfo = {
  blogName: blogName,
  followLink: "http://www.bloglovin.com"+followLink;
  blogSite: blogSite
};
myArray.push(blogInfo);
```

Comment: that looks great.  So, how could I use the urls within followLink to scrape each individual page?